# Why is visual studio code telling me that cout is not a member of std namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup visual studio code to program in c++. I have already installed the extensions **C/C++** and **C/C++ Intellisense**

Following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout<< "hello" ;
}
```

The error I'm getting is `identifier cout is undefined` and when I write it as `std::cout` the error I get then is `namespace std has no member cout` . 
Following is my `task.json` file:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "make",
"isShellCommand": true,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Makefile",
        // Make this the default build command.
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
        "showOutput": "always",
        // No args
        "args": ["all"],
        // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: [Your code builds fine on VC++](http://rextester.com/SUJY5236).

Comment: Is your source file a cpp file or a c file? Perhaps the compiler is confused about the language because of the file extension. Another possibility is that the installation is corrupted and there is no `cout` in `iostream`. Try reinstalling...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Its a **bug**.

There is a workaround for this bug, go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings` in VS Code and change

`"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default"` to `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"`

Comment: Fyi: This bug and its solution still exist. My VSCode version is: `Version: 1.45.0, Commit: d69a79b73808559a91206d73d7717ff5f798f23c`.

Thanks again for the solution! :)

Comment: Still exists: `1.55.2 3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d x64`

Comment: > namespace "std" has no member "unordered_set" C/C++(135)
Still there and the workaround works!

C/C++ extension: `ms-vscode.cpptools  v1.13.9`

VS Code:
`Version: 1.74.3 (user setup)
Commit: 97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534
Date: 2023-01-09T16:59:02.252Z`

Comment: Having a link to an actual bug  (github issue) would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

I am using VSCode version 1.22.2 with MinGW compiler and below config works for me:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "MinGW",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed",
                "C:/MinGW/include/*"
                "${workspaceRoot}",
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
],
"version": 3
}
```

Refer these link too:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/MinGW.md

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem and found that it is a vscode bug.
Please refer to the link below.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/743

Comment: Not from some time: "closed this as completed on Aug 2, 2018".

Answer (score 1):

I too experienced the same issue after the VS Code Updated to v1.57.
After a long time spending on what's the issue, I have come to know that it is a bug due to this recent update. It has also updated the existing installed extensions which I had. **C/C++ Microsoft** Extension-*(C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing.)* is also one among them. It was also updated from 1.4.0 to 1.4.1.
So I finally sorted out that the actual bug was in this extension's v1.4.1 So I downgraded again to old version which was working fine for me.

Steps to Install Old version of same extension:

1. Click the Extension
2. Click down arrow near Uninstall
3. Click Install Another Version...
4. And now install the version which worked fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with vscode to not detect #define constants from other files. Solved this for me by going to: **file > preferences > Settings > Extentions > C/C++**

Scroll down to **C_Cpp › Default: Intelli Sense Mode** and change the value from default to your compiler (gcc-x64 in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add #include iostream.
After adding the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f4</kbd> and restarted vscode. The error was gone!

Answer (score 0):

What works for me, is just deleting the `iostream` or `bits/stdc++.h` include, saving the document and adding it again. This fixes the issue without restarting VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change the settings of the extension, as it is also specified that doing so gives "fuzzy" intellisense.

I was able to solve the problem by fixing the c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
"intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
```

which might have been changed as you switch devices. I worked on both Windows and Mac, so doing this will automatically identify the system you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it occurred because inconsistent compiler settings:

1. I have both Visual Studio and TDM-GCC-64 installed in Windows
2. I configured the vscode setting `C_Cpp > Default: System Include Path` to include directories of TDM-GCC-64
3. I keep the vscode setting `C_Cpp › Default: Compiler Path` empty (at the same time vscode automatically detects my Visual Studio and uses it as Compiler Path)

solution: configure also `C_Cpp › Default: Compiler Path` to `path/to/gcc.exe`