# namespace "std" has no member "cout" ("cin", "endl",... are the same)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, std

Recently I re-installed C++ for my course at university after a long time. After installing the C++ Extension pack, I tested with "HelloWorld" code and found that all the members from namespace "std" make errors like in the following images. I can still compile and run it as usual, but the errors shown make me so displeased.

I tried to find some solutions. All of them related to missing `#include<iostream>`, `using namespace std`, changing the `intelliSenseMode`, `C_Cpp.errorSquiggles`, or something else, but none of them was the correct answer.

Why might this be happening?

Here are my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "D:/Code/Path/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
            "D:/Code/Path/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include",
            "D:/Code/Path/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"            
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

settings.json:

```
{
"cSpell.words": [
    "heapify",
    "HUST",
    "Inorder"
],
"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "EnabledIfIncludesResolve"
```

}

hello-world.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post text as images. You seem to have a mix of compilers in your `cpp_properties.json`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry for the images, my account is new so its can not embed image in this post. The compilers path is still default after i installed extension, was it wrong somewhere?

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong?

Comment: I tried to compile and its ran normally, so maybe not

Comment: You are trying to run a Visual Studio compiler with mingw includes. This will not work. Pick one compiler and stick to it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. i changed the compilerPath to c++.exe in bin folder and its really worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Oh i forgot to change the images to text, thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [Why is visual studio code telling me that cout is not a member of std namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094817/why-is-visual-studio-code-telling-me-that-cout-is-not-a-member-of-std-namespace) answer, it should be a bug in VS code.

You should go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings` in VS Code and change

`"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default"` to `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"`. Maybe this answer helps!

Comment: I also tried it but after choose "Tag Parser", the IDE doesn't show any errors, even the errors are true.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/743

Answer (score 0):

So after `@AlanBirtles` and `@n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem` comments, i tried to change the compilerPath to `../mingw64/bin/c++.exe` and its really worked. Maybe the default path of C/C++ extension provided is wrong in some ways. Thank you so much everyone

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "D:/Code/Path/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
            "D:/Code/Path/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include",
            "D:/Code/Path/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        // "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
        "compilerPath": "D:/Code/Path/mingw64/bin/c++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        // "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}