# VS Code: namespace "std" has no member "format" message but it compiles

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have written some code in Visual Studio 2022 that I then copy over to VS Code in order to compile it to a node module. I get no errors in Visual Studio, but get the following error in VS Code:

`namespace "std" has no member "format" C/C++(135)`.

The code compiles without errors and works fine, but my workspace is polluted with error messages.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me to the cause of the messages and of course how to suppress them.

Here is a detailed compiler information:

```
> node-gyp rebuild -j max && set_modules && tsc && node ./final/index.js

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.2.32519.379) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
```

Comment: That looks like an error, not a warning. Are you sure it actually compiles? If you remove executable from your folder, will it still be generated again after you compile?

Comment: `gcc` does not have an implementation of `std::format` yet. You can use a third-party library that does much of the same thing [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen : Yes, it **definitely** compiles. I'm working on it right now, making changes, etc. that are reflected in the module.

Comment: Most IDEs use a different "compiler" for syntax highlighting as they do for the actual compilation. The difference is almost certainly down to that. `std::format` is C++20 and onwards.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. : I'm using `node-gyp` for complilation and it is using VS2022 (17.2).

Comment: Looks like you are getting intellisense errors and not compiler errors. You want to be able to differentiate between the two, and tell us what you are getting when asking questions.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. :  Okay, thanks for the feedback. I did say the code compiles and that the workspace is polluted with errors, I thought that was clear enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code C++ extension gives error "namespace has no member function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081196/vs-code-c-extension-gives-error-namespace-has-no-member-function), or maybe this: [c++ - Why is visual studio code telling me that cout is not a member of std namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094817/why-is-visual-studio-code-telling-me-that-cout-is-not-a-member-of-std-namespace)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS Code creates a `.vscode` folder with a file `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Changing the line `"cppStandard": "c++17",` to `"cppStandard": "c++20",` enables IntelliSense for C++20.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue. I added `"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20"` to `.vscode/setting.json` for this issue and solved it.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. What actually helped was the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/44081196/2932052 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/44094817/2932052